# How can I split this string on comma and quotation mark?

Tags: java, split

I read from a text file and sometimes I get in a string something like:

```
;onor Oyj,Native,Uor Oyj1,"Uponor Oyj, UBS, Innovation AB",39639d4d26:-21f7;
```

I need to split the string like this:

```
'onor Oyj',  
'Native',  
'Uor Oyj1',  
'Uponor Oyj, UBS, Innovation AB',  
'39639d4d26:-21f7',  
';'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Itried to replace " with ' but then I do not know how to continue

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
  String str = ";onor Oyj,Native,Uor Oyj1,\"Uponor Oyj, UBS, Innovation AB\",39639d4d26:-21f7;";
  char[] c = str.toCharArray();
  boolean inQuote = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
  {
     if (c[i] == ',' && !inQuote)
        c[i] = '\01'; // some value that doesn't appear in the string
     if (c[i] == '"')
        inQuote = !inQuote;
  }
  String[] arr2 = String.valueOf(c).split("\\01");
  for (String s: arr2)
  {
     System.out.println(s);
  }
```

Outputs:

```
;onor Oyj
Native
Uor Oyj1
"Uponor Oyj, UBS, Innovation AB"
39639d4d26:-21f7;
```

Replace `String[] arr2 = String.valueOf(c).split("\\01");` with `String[] arr2 = String.valueOf(c).replaceAll("\"", "").split("\\01");` to remove the quotes.